# Grouping by another variable - boxplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet-wrap

I am trying to create a boxplot where I can group one variable by the levels of a second variable. I have worked out how to facet wrap, but how do I get all the bars on the same plot?

I need to create the following:

x-axis:  Time period (TP) - 4 levels, 1 -4.

y-axis:  CV (coefficient of variation data).

Boxplots: 4 boxplots to appear at each level of the x-axis.  Split accross 4 levels of the second factor, CS (calf status, categorical, 1 - 4)

I can create split boxplots using facet_wrap using the following code:

```
p10 <- ggplot(model.data, aes(x = as.factor(TP), y=CV)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Time period") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Coefficient of variation (CV)\nof adult females' association indicies") +
  ggtitle("CV adult females' association indicies by time period \n split out by calf status, 1 - 4 ") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  facet_grid(~CS)
p10
```

But how do I get this info all on a single boxplot?

I am trying to make it look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your boxplot on a single plot you should add `fill` in `aes` and not `facet_wrap` :

```
p10 <- ggplot(model.data, aes(x = as.factor(TP), y=CV, fill=CS)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Time period") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Coefficient of variation (CV)\nof adult females' association indicies") +
  ggtitle("CV adult females' association indicies by time period \n split out by calf status, 1 - 4 ") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
p10
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I tried that and I get the error message: "Warning message:
Removed 4 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot). " and the boxplot does not change.

Comment: Do you remove `facet_grid` ? The warning is only about missing or inifinite values in one of the feature you use.